# How can I change the background color of a single Showit canvas?

Tags: css, background-color

For testing sake I have a page and want the canvas with the image to have a black background. I've tried targeting both the class and id of this section but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the code I have currently

```
<style>

#section-one .sb.sib-section-one.sb-nd-dH {
background-color:#000 !important;
}
</style>
```

And here is the link to the page > https://den-of-dreamers-51.showitpreview.com/new-page-1

Would love any insight on how to target the section so I can use the same technique in other areas of the site. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There's no such `#section-one .sb.sib-section-one.sb-nd-dH` rule in your styles - and even if there was one your `.sc` is covering entirely that DIV - so you won't be able to see the #000 background anyways. If instead you add a rule like `.sc {background: #000;}` there you go. Black. Please learn how to use Dev tools, inspect element and play with styles.

Comment: Make sure you are targeting your *class* correctly.